# Time in the morning for breakfast/time for breakfast in the morning?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, sentence-patterns, compound-words

Can anyone help me out here?

Which is right and more standard among the following?:

1. I don't have time in the morning for breakfast

   ```
                **OR**
   ```
2. I don't have time for breakfast in the morning

While conversing with colleagues option 1) slipped out of my tongue and I'm afraid if the first sentence is incorrect.

Please share your opinions

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that's perhaps "incorrect" with your sentences is that they are pleonastic. Of course, breakfast is had in the morning only.

So perhaps you could have said "I don't have time for breakfasts."

Comment: And pleonasm is in the written-off list?@user405662

Comment: Pleonastic? Redundancy is not always bad. The OP's sentences might be good if the speaker wanted to say specifically that their *morning* schedule is too near full to allow time for breakfast (rather than making a more general statement about being busy all the time).

Comment: Good point, Rosie F. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your efforts ..really helpful@user405662

Comment: Apt explanation. Thanks @RosieF